# Passing This Parameter In AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How do I pass the html element through my function when using AngularJS. This would work if you don't use AngularJS, but I think AngularJS confuses the "this" keyword with some other parent. How would I get this code to work?

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.MyFunction = function(element) {
    alert(element.value);
    element.focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-click="MyFunction(this)" value="Hello">
</div>
```

Comment: This will not work. You need to write the directive to set focus on `input`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set focus on input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field)

Comment: You have all the html element in your link function within the element param already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

```
<input ng-click="MyFunction($event)" value="Hello">

  // while in your controller

angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.MyFunction = function($event) {

  //reference to the DOM element triggered the function
   var element =   $event.target;   
    element.focus();
  }
});
```

BUT ITS NOT GOOD PRACTICE TO DO IT THIS WAY IN ANGULAR JS

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this isn't good practice please? Because this solves my problem perfectly

Comment: look here, it explains well. 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032855/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-idea-to-manipulate-dom-in-controllers)

and if you want to use them directives are the best:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480150/manipulating-dom-in-angularjs-best-practice)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ng-model` for assigning values to element and that's 2 way binding :)

```js
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.theValue = "Hello";
      $scope.MyFunction = function(value) {
        alert('Passed Value : ' + value  + ' Model Value : ' + $scope.theValue);
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-model="theValue" ng-blur="MyFunction(theValue)">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I know about ng-model but you can't do something like element.focus() with ng-model. So ng-model doesn't solve my problem here

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can't work this way, try with `event.target`. You should try following way:

```
    <input ng-click="MyFunction()" value="Hello">

    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.MyFunction = function() {
        alert($(event.target).attr('value'));
        $(event.target).focus();
      }
    });
```