# How to overcome syntax error issue while Injecting Javascript code from angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add the following javascript code through one angular controller

```
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = false;

    script.setAttribute('src', './exampleJSCode.js');
```

The exampleJSCode file contains javascript functions but when I run this code I get lots of syntax errors (around 54) but the exampleJSCode file is formatted correctly.

How to escape that character which is causing syntax error?

Comment: What errors? Can you provide a snippet of the errors being generated in your IDE? Also, you should never modify the DOM from an Angular controller.

Comment: oh ohk, btw what are other ways, like i am in need of having the functions in the exampleJSCode file as a javascript functions in order to capture few events. Should I write them in angular and just pass the reference of that function in javascript function directly put in index.jsp file?

Comment: Execution pack-angular-js of goal net.alchim31.maven:yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.5.1:compress failed: Compilation produced 54 syntax errors.

Comment: Per the angularjs docs, the only truly acceptable place to modify the DOM is from a directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#dom-manipulation
Here is another SO article on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480150/manipulating-dom-in-angularjs-best-practice

From your last comment it looks like your code has syntax errors which is why it isn't compiling. You need to view it from an IDE that highlights those for you or you need to find a way to have your pack-angular-js step output those syntax errors in the log and fix them.